# Generating Sequencial ID with Suffix and Prefix in php

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanted to create sequential ID with suffix and prefix in php. I have done some of the parts but, i need to do that if the id existed in DB variable $i shall be incremented by one to generate the next sequential unique id. I have done this but the ID didn't increment after 2. So any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

**this is the code that check the id exist in the db and generate next unique id number.**

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 1000; $i++) {

        $formnum = sprintf('%04d', $i);
       $id2 = "Prefix".$formnum.date("Y");
        $q = "SELECT * FROM table where id='$id2'";
       $chk = new DBConnection();
      $opchk = $chk->executeQuery($q);

      $fetres = mysql_num_rows($opchk);
      if( $fetres >0){

          $i = $i + 1;
          do {
              $formnum = sprintf('%04d', $i);
              return $formnum ;
          }while ($i<=1000);

        }else{
      return $formnum ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to generate your own unique id. Use AUTOINCREMENT instead and it is all done by MYSQL

Comment: Even if the above code did work, it would be really inefficient. Imagine, if you already have 999 records for a given prefix, your code would issue 1000 selects to determine the next possible value. But this question has been asked multiple times already here on SO.